# How can i add a param to the existing url?...Django...Paginator

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, pagination

I have made a page with which displays some data from the database. I have added a paginator to my website. my website also has a search bar. so when the user searches for something....the URL is...

```
.../search/?q=xyz
```

so when I paginate the searched data with...

```
<a href="?page={{ walls.next_page_number }}"> next page </a>
```

it makes the URL as...

```
.../search/?page=2
```

but that's an error...but, I want something like this...

```
.../search/?q=xyz&page=2
```

how can I achieve this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a template tag to dynamically combine the get parameters to your paginator.

Here's an example of how I do this;

```py
from django import template
from django.utils.http import urlencode

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def url_replace(context, **kwargs):
    query = context['request'].GET.dict()
    query.update(kwargs)
    return urlencode(query)
```

```html
{% load url_replace %}

            <div class="pagination-container">
                <ul class="pagination">
                    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                        <li class="pagination-item">
                            <a href="?{% url_replace page=1 %}">first</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="pagination-item">
                            <a href="?{% url_replace page=page_obj.previous_page_number %}">previous</a>
                        </li>
                    {% endif %}
                    <li class="pagination-item">
                        <span class="current">
                            Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
                        </span>
                    </li>

                    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                        <li class="pagination-item">
                            <a href="?{% url_replace page=page_obj.next_page_number %}">next</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="pagination-item">
                            <a href="?{% url_replace page= page_obj.paginator.num_pages %}">last</a>
                        </li>
                    {% endif %}
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: This worked for me very well....thank you so much I was trying this for the last 2 days ..finally thank you so much.... :)....
.
just one request can u explain whats going on in the url_replace()

Comment: Sure, it takes the `GET` params that are on your request, adds them to the kwargs that you need from the paginator and encodes them so that they'll work in a URL so that they can be passed with the link.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to write a relative URI that preserves the existing query string while adding additional parameters to it.

You have to add your parameter to the actual url that your link looks like this:

`<a href="?q=xyz&page=2"> next page </a>`

or something like this:

`<a href="/search?q=xyz&page=2"> next page </a>`

I think you get it :)